# Pointer to a function

Tags: c

What is the difference between `int *fun(void)` and  `int fun*(void)` ?

Comment: They look incomplete and out of context in different ways? Please clarify your question.

Comment: You mean except the fact that the second one is wrong and it won't compile ?

Comment: Why did you name this post pointer to a function?

Comment: Krtek's answer was sarcasm. The point is that's a huge difference and there's no point in trying to imagine some other difference.

Answer (score 6):

The former starts to define (or declare, depending on what comes next) a function that returns a pointer to `int`. The latter is a syntax error. Neither are function pointers.

A function pointer needs to look like this:

```
int (*fun)(void);
```

This declares a pointer to a function that returns `int`.

Comment: With in a minute difference, our answers turned out to be similar. I think, I should learn typing fast at least for the sake of S0 :)

Answer (score 3):

```
int* fun(void);
```

`fun` do not take any arguments but returns a pointer to an integer. And I think, second one is syntactically wrong. If you are trying to for a function pointer, then it should be -

```
int (*fun)(void)= NULL;
```

Now, `fun` is pointer to a function that takes no arguments but returns an integer.

Answer (score 0):

int* func(void)

Generally a valid declaration has 3 three parts, and end with ; semicolon.

Part 1)
Argument

void mean - no argument 
(argument can be as complicated and vary in number)

Part 2)
Return Type (can be user type or build in)

int* mean - (return type) is pointer to int

Part 3)
Name of the Function (can be anything, should be logical to the operation it is going to perform.

func mean - name of the function

In the second syntex.
we have * in between part 2 and part 3.

which is not allowed and meaningful.
either you can add * to void or int.

- int * func (void)
- int func (void *)

or for function pointer as answered.

(*pf) ();

or

(*pf) (void)